# Images for retina screen (@2x)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, sprite-kit, retina-display

Now I am making a Game with spritekit(swift) in Xcode 6.

It has to be playable for iPhone 4s and higher.
But as far as I know are all iphones from 4s and higher Retina so I can add all images with (750 x 1334 pix) and with @2x.png.

So I do not need to add images without @2x..

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: If you have a 512 x 512 (1x) image and you want it to support (2x and 3x) you have to include those 2 files like this:

```
yourImage.png       // (512x512 at 1x)
yourImage@2x.png    // (1024x1024 at 2x)
yourImage@3x.png    // (1536x1536 at 3x)
```

Answer (score 1):

"[iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)" lists asset sizes for the current devices, which includes the 4s. The only current devices with @1x displays are iPads.

Unless you know that iPads won't run your app (which I don't think you can do, as they can run all apps in stretch mode) you will want to include @1x sizes.

In any event, you will probably want to include a @1x icon, as the app store is (I think) still visible to people on older devices, and your app may be rejected without it.

Also, don't forget @3x if you want to support the iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: "Unless you know that iPads won't run your app you will want to include @1x sizes." Using 2x icons on a 1x device will simply show it the same as if you shrunk it yourself; the only difference might be it uses more memory.

Comment: "as the app store is (I think) still visible to people on older devices" I don't think he is asking about app store icons, but about icons in the app.

Comment: @user102008 Using 2x does indeed work; I guess I had never tested it before. In that case it becomes a question of memory/performance. The devices that don't have retina are the least capable of handling the larger images. (If that is or is not something the asker cares about)